# How to get from Jerusalem to Ben Gurion airport on Saturday?

Tags: airports, israel

I'm staying in Jerusalem and flying out from Ben Gurion airport on a Saturday, when the public transport does not function. What is the best way to get there?

Comment: I assume you can take a taxi ?

Comment: @Max - Yes, but that's not perfect, would be pretty expensive presumably.

Comment: If there's no public transport, then your choices are limited, whether taxi or uber style transport.

Comment: There should be jitneys from Jerusalem to Tel Aviv, and from Tel Aviv Bus Terminal to airport. Maybe direct ones too.

Answer (score 8):

[Nesher Tours](http://www.neshertours.co.il/) is the operator licensed by the [Israeli Airport Authority](http://www.iaa.gov.il/he-IL/airports/BenGurion/Transportation/Pages/Taxi.aspx) to operate shuttles to Jerusalem, they operate 24 hours a day, 7 days a week (except for Yom Kippur). On their site they have two different services:

- Taxi to BGA: costs 64 NIS for pickup from anywhere, or less for pickup from their station.
- Suttle to BGA: costs 61.9 NIS, picks up from anywhere.

I couldn't understand from the site what is the difference between the two services. In either case, you need to call them to coordinate, their phone number is 02-6257227 (or 072-264-6059, 1599-500-205).

Comment: I'm not affiliated with the company in any way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular operator, but usually a "taxi" is private while a "shuttle" is shared with other customers.  You'd expect more than 3 shekels of discount for the latter though.

Comment: @jpatokal, that's why I don't understand the differences between the two. I found a company that takes 180-210 NIS for a "normal" taxi so I think that both cases are a shared service.

Comment: (I speak Hebrew) I only see the 64 shekel price. If I had to guess, if say the 61.9 was before some recent price increase. Also, "their station" is just the central bus station in Jerusalem; if you can get there it's only 38 shekels.

Comment: @JoeyMarianer look at the section "[הסעות לנתב"ג](http://www.neshertours.co.il/הסעות_לנתבג)" on their site.

Comment: You're right. I just missed it because I was on my phone. Still strange that the two options are just 2.10 ILS apart, though.

Comment: I think they might have updated one page and not the other...

Comment: I think that a shuttle has pre-assigned stops ( like a bus ) and a taxi comes to your location. both are shared ( usually 6-8 people ). not sure though.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Israel Airport Authority:

Nesher shuttle to Jerusalem and the surrounding regions depart from the service post on Level G, next to Gates 01-03. There are signs directing to the post.
The service operates 24 hours a day. 
Telephone: 02-6257227
Fees:
Service fee to passenger's address:
Mevaseret Zion, Ma'ale​ Hahamisha, Beit Zait, Abu Gosh, Kiryat Anavim, Shoresh, Beit Meir, Shoeva, Beit Nekofa​, Harel Interchange  64 NIS (about $21 US)
Central Jerusalem 69 NIS (about $23 US)
Ma'ale Adumim   55 (about $15 US)

A Taxi service like Bar Ilan (private Taxi) costs 200 NIS (about $67 US). They do not operate on Saturday day (but you will be able to order a taxi from 8pm until about 2:30 am on Saturday Night).  Taxi Drivers should be available at the terminal listed above and you can order a taxi via the IAA to make sure you're not ripped off.